# Is there a quick and easy way to pronounce "W" letter?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronunciation, slang, word-usage

I mean, there is a well known 'substitution' for number "0" with 'ou' sound. Like, '107' in military communications will be pronounced as 'one-ou-seven'. Is there similar kind of substitution for letter "W", say, in aforementioned military comms? Some way that allows to pronounce it much quicker?

Comment: People tend to just shorten it naturally, as 'dubyou' or 'dubya'. The military use some kind of [able baker charlie thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) where it is  pronounced 'whiskey'.

Comment: @Mitch: *able baker*'s the *old* phonetic alphabet ;-) The new one's [alfa, bravo, charlie, delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet)...

Comment: I am often amused by the acronym "WWU" that represents Western Washington University, in Bellingham where I live. "WWU" takes three letters, but seven syllables /'dəbəlyu'dəbəlyu'yu/, whereas _Western Washington_ takes only five syllables /'wɛstərn'wɔʃɪŋtən/. I usually just pronounce "WWU" as /'wuwu/; that's common enough that everybody understands.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other known pronunciations, aside from the rapid pronunciation *duhb-yuh*. You might portray a different meaning if you used other words/sounds to represent the standard pronunciation. *Whiskey* is widely accepted to represent the letter.